# Convert tiff image into String to be posted as binary application/octet-stream (C++)

Tags: c++, http, post, c-strings

I'm using C++ Sockets to make an HTTP Multipart POST containing a TIFF image to a server. This server expects a binary octet-stream.

What I've tried is this:

```
// Convert out data into a string that can be appended to the body
std::ifstream fin(fileName, std::ios::binary);
std::ostringstream ostrm;
ostrm << fin.rdbuf();
string data(ostrm.str());
```

Unfortunately, I just get II*, when the data should be much longer. My guess is that the data contains a NULL character, which makes C++ think the String is finished. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

If it helps, this is my body constructing code:

```
string constructBody(string batchId, string fileString, string fileName) {
    string body;
    string CRLF = "\r\n";

    // first we add the args
    body.append("--" + string(BOUNDARY) + CRLF);
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"batch_id\"" + CRLF);
    body.append(CRLF);
    body.append(batchId + CRLF);
    body.append("--" + string(BOUNDARY) + CRLF);

    // now we add the file
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"front\"; filename=\"" + string(fileName) + "\"" + CRLF);
    body.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + CRLF);
    body.append("Content-Transfer-Encording: binary" + CRLF);
    body.append(CRLF);
    body.append(fileString + CRLF);
    body.append("--" + string(BOUNDARY) + "--" + CRLF);
    body.append(CRLF);

    return body;
}
```

And here is the posting code:

```
string body = constructBody(batchId, data, "Front.tif");
char header[1024];
sprintf(header, "POST %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: %s\r\n"
    "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
    "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s\r\n"
    "Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n\r\n", RECEIVER, IP, strlen(body.c_str()), BOUNDARY);
int p = send(dataSock, header, strlen(header), 0);
int k = send(dataSock, body.c_str(), strlen(body.c_str()), 0);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot use `printf` in the way that you're using it to display a string that contains embedded  nulls.

Comment: Right, the printf is left over from something else. I'm viewing the String in the visual studio debugger

Comment: Are you using the memory window?  That is what you need to use to view a string that has embedded nulls, not the usual "watch" window.

Comment: I'm in the Autos window. I can also look at the POST on the other end and see that it's just sending II*. I was able to make this post using Java quite easily using MultipartEntityBuilder and FileBody's... This showed that the file is II* followed by a whole bunch of binary junk. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this in C++

Comment: @Noah: It's _very_ easy in C++. Unfortunately you appear to be using the components from _C_ that make it as hard as possible :)

Comment: @Noah Avoid using functions that use the null-terminator as a string terminator.  That is the simple answer.  You're using std::string, but you failed to use the functions that std::string provides to get the actual length of the data.  Instead you went the 'C' route, which is the reason for most of your issues you're seeing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use functions that uses the null as a string terminator:

`int k = send(dataSock, body.c_str(), strlen(body.c_str()), 0);`

You're using `strlen` above.  This is not correct.

The fix for this is to use the `length()` function for `std::string`:

`int k = send(dataSock, body.c_str(), body.length()), 0);`

You make the same error in other places, such as when you create the header:

`"Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n\r\n", RECEIVER, IP, strlen(body.c_str()), BOUNDARY);`

should be:

`"Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n\r\n", RECEIVER, IP, body.length(), BOUNDARY);`

Comment: Why would you write `strlen(aStdString.c_str())` o.O